# How do you select a default value in v-select from Vuex from two stores?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuetify.js

I have a v-select that I populate from a Vuex-store. I need to select the value in the v-select that matches the ID of a property in another object that I get from a computed property(customer), but cant seem to get it to work.

I dont want to mutate state, I just want to display the matching dropdown value according to the ID of priceListId on the customer-object.

V-select:

```
 <v-select :items="priceLists"
                      item-text="name"
                      item-value="id"
                      label="pricelist"
                      v-model="select"
                      select
                      return-object></v-select>
```

Code for models:

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    select: null
    }),
    computed: {
    priceLists () {
      return this.$store.state.pricelists.pricelists
    },
    customer () {
     return this.$store.state.customers.customers.find(customer => 
      customer.id === Number(this.customer.id))
 }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry could you be 100% clear on what your purpose is i dont rly understand it, and you cant use the computed value inside its own computed I dont think that will give correct results

Comment: I have 1 array of pricelists and a object of type customer. I populate the v-select with pricelists from the array. The customer-object has a property called priceListId. Now I want the V-select to set the default selected value to the property of priceListId so that you can see which pricelist the customer has, and change it. Hope the explanation works! :)

Comment: Idk i tried to do a fiddle but your whole customer id and pricelist id im still not sure what you want exactly... maybe im just stupid

Answer (score 1):

Use a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on `customer` to automatically set `select` (the v-model of the price list `<v-select>`) to the desired price list by `customer.priceListId`:

```
watch: {
  customer: {
    immediate: true,
    handler(value) {
      this.select = value.priceListId;
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/8z0yr481v2?module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue)